# Check c++ version in windows

Tags: c++, version

When I try

```
cpp -v
```

It shows I have gcc 4.9.2 installed.
How do I check the current C++ version that I have installed on my Windows computer ?

Thanks !

EDIT:

Trying with

```
g++ -v
```

gives me this result -

[image]

Comment: You mean version of the compiler? `g++ -v` should do the trick

Comment: Do you mean the C++ *standard* version supported by GCC 4.9.2? How about [reading the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.4/gcc/)?

Comment: The screenshot in your question shows the version at the bottom...

Comment: @Pezo I already know the gcc version. I need to know the g++ version.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. These are the same, gcc/cpp and g++ are just two different frontends (C and C++, respectively) for the same compiler.

Comment: You tried install mingw x32 OR x64 ? I think that in your case is x64

Comment: This doesn't show the C++ *STANDARD*. How can I check for the C++ standard used by my compiler (gcc 11) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `g++ -v` or `gcc -v` which will give you your compiler version.

You can also go to your windows settings, click on "Apps" go to the search bar and search up `c++` scroll down to the last item, and click on it.  The version should be displayed fairly obviously for you.

[Microsoft Visual C++ version displayed from Microsoft Window's Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykiRA.png)

Answer (score 5):

Try using **g++ --version** command at cmd Because for me also g++ -version or g++ -v command hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

g++ -v 
(To check g++ version in window through cmd workes fine)

Answer (score -3):

Just go to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

[image]

Choose one and click.

Comment: How does that help with finding out what version of `c++` they have on their system?